# OS X Terminal is choking on color

Tags: macos, terminal, colors, git

My friend helped me get colors in my OS X Terminal by having my copy some preferences into a file somewhere. Now when I try to run 'git commit' I get this message:

**fatal: bad config variable 'color.status.name' **

I've looked all over and can't find the file we changed. I don't have a ~/.bash_profile or a ~/.bashrc file. My ~/.profile is blank. Ideas? I've tried iTerm and get the same thing. I'm on OS X 10.6.2 if it matters.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, turns out it was ~/.gitconfig. Makes sense.